# Opacity of Panel over Awesomium WebControl

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel, opacity, awesomium

I've got a normal Winforms Panel, but under it, I've sent a (Awesomium) WebControl form to the back, and was wondering if it's possible to make the panel transparent to reveal the colors of the webpage basically, but simple solutions such as

```
Panel1.BackColor = FromARGB(0,0,0,0) (Or any other color)
```

make the backcolor the same as the Form's backcolor (Goes right through the WebControl). Is there any workaround? My original intent was to see if the panel could display the color under of the webpage, rather than the Form's backcolor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, you have not explained your problem properly, so I can't tell exactly what problem you are getting.

`Panel`'s color is by default `transparent` but for your convenience you can set the background as `transparent`.

Here is the code:

```
Panel1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

Or, if your form's `backcolor` is a plain color, you can try the following:

```
Panel1.BackColor = Form1.BackColor
```

Hope it works perfectly!

Comment: Ah, I've already tried this, and by default, transparent goes to the color of the form's background, not the color of the web page within the web control.